# Turn fonts to Monospaced

Tags: java, swing, text-editor

I am trying to make a bizarre text editor for people with reading problems with Netbeans. You load the text you like and the editor starts highlighting it word by word with bold letters. The change from plain to bold constantly change the word dimensions and moves the line. One solution was the Monospaced Font but I would like to add a few more fonts available for the user to choose. Is there any way to do this with Arial for example by giving some orders to the JTextPane?

Comment: *I would like every word (which means every letter) to keep its dimensions either is plain or bold* hmm ... technically, that's a bit self contradictory, isn't it :-) Just trying to understand: you want the plain text to be at the same place as the bold, with enough white space around that the bold version just fills it, kind of growing effect without jumping? If so, there's nothing off the shelf. You'll probably have to write custom View/-Factory

Comment: _...Surly I don't want the line to change but also i want the word stay stable not trembling...Just fattening..._ I don't think there is any contradiction here. Like i wrote in the title i want to give monospaced attributes to non monospaced fonts.

Comment: <shrugs> if you don't care to make me understand what you _really_ want, just be happy :-)

Comment: Maybe i don't understand what you don't understand.If its the way i say it you could ask @Dave.How can i be happy when i cant help people with reading problems?I am referring to my unclear and not useful question.

Comment: Why do you tag the question `Ǹetbeans`? If you happen to develop in Norway, you would tag it `Norway`?

Answer (score 0):

You can manually split the String with `<br/>` by counting characters and splitting at the right spot to keep the width under your desired character width.  Give some leeway so if you get a big word, it won't still go to the next line.

Alternatively, you could use a JList to display your lines (instead of using `<br/>`).  That way, there's no way the line would split to the next line.  However, if you do it that way, the user will click on the list like a list and not be able to select text like in a normal text pane.

Comment: I would like every word (which means every letter) to keep its dimensions either is plain or bold.Surly I don't want the line to change but also i want the word stay stable not trembling...Just fattening...

Comment: I don't know if there's a way to do what you want in a text pane, but I doubt it.  You could try underlining instead of using bold.

Comment: No, I think the problem is inherent in using HTML / WebKit to display fonts.  By not being able to specifically set the size of each word, you are going to get the size changing when you change the font.  That's just the way fonts work.

Comment: I am not going to put this in a webpage if thats what you mean with HTML/WebKit. I was thinking changing Font metrics...